# Reverse DNS in email does not work: Received from mail.example.org (unkown [1.2.3.4.6])

Tags: email, dns, reverse, postfix-mta

This is the email header of one of our notification mails send through SMTP:

> Received: from mgi74201.gutt.it (mgi74201.gutt.it. [5.9.63.186]) by
>   mx.google.com with ESMTP id ABCD1234; Wed, 08 Aug 2012
>   09:36:18 -0700 (PDT) Received: from mgi74201.gutt.it (unknown
>   [5.9.63.186]) (Authenticated sender: noreply@maxrev.de) by
>   mgi74201.gutt.it (Postfix) with ESMTPA id ABCD1234 for
>   <***@gmail.com>; Wed, 8 Aug 2012 18:35:55 +0200 (CEST)

As you can see google was able to check PTR:5.9.63.186 (resulting mgi74201.gutt.it.), but our own mail client results "unknown".

We've tested `nslookup 5.9.63.186` and it results as expected:

> Using username "abc".  Authenticating with public key "abc"  Last
>   login: Wed Aug  8 19:31:01 2012 from 123.abc  root@mgi74201:~#
>   nslookup 5.9.63.186  Server:         8.8.4.4  Address:
>   8.8.4.4#53    Non-authoritative answer: 
>   186.63.9.5.in-addr.arpa name = mgi74201.gutt.it.    Authoritative answers can be found from:    abc@mgi74201:~#

So why does the Reverse DNS not work? A postfix related problem?

EDIT: postfix results:

> Aug  9 17:00:59 mgi74201 postfix/smtpd[19261]: warning: 5.9.63.186:
>   address not listed for hostname mgi74201.gutt.it Aug  9 17:00:59
>   mgi74201 postfix/smtpd[19261]: connect from unknown[5.9.63.186]

But hosts file seems to be correct:

```
# 'hosts' file configuration. 

::ffff:5.9.63.186     mgi74201.gutt.it     mgi74201 
::1     ip6-localhost     ip6-loopback 
fe00::0     ip6-localnet 
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters 
ff02::3     ip6-allhosts 
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost mgi74201.gutt.it.local 
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment. 
5.9.63.186 mgi74201.gutt.it  mgi74201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the last line of your `hosts` file into first position.
The effect should be that `mgi74201.gutt.it` will get resolved to `5.9.63.186` instead of `::ffff:5.9.63.186`

Or, maybe better, assign a different hostname to the IPv6 address, just like `ip6-localhost` differs from `localhost`.

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem was IPv6. Because the hosts file is generated automatically through the Control panel and can't be edited, we decided to deactivate IPv6 temporarily until we find a better solution.